# Save playbook information to hosts file

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that spins up a new droplet on DigitalOcean using the core module built into Ansible:

```
- name: Provision droplet on DigitalOcean
  local_action: digital_ocean
    state=present
    ssh_key_ids=1234
    name=mydroplet
    client_id=ABC
    api_key=ABC
    size_id=1
    region_id=2
    image_id=3
    wait_timeout=500
  register: my_droplet
- debug: msg="ID is {{ my_droplet.droplet.id }}"
- debug: msg="Your droplet has the IP address of {{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
```

I run this using (note the local argument):

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/create_droplet.yml -c local -i playbooks/hosts
```

My hosts file initially looks like this:

```
[production]
TBA

[localhost]
localhost
```

When the above playbook finishes I can see the debug information in STDOUT:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Your droplet has the IP address of 255.255.255.255"
}
```

Is there any way for this playbook to retain the `my_droplet.ip_address` variable and save the TBA in the hosts file instead of having to manually copy-pasta it there? I ask because I want to add this provisioning playbook to a ruby script that subsequently bootstraps the VPS with another playbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm launching instances with ec2, and I originally wanted to do the same thing.  I found some examples of using lineinfile and massaging it to the do the same thing as so:

```
  - name: Launching new instances for {{ application }} 
    local_action: ec2 group={{ security_group }} instance_type={{ instance_type}} image={{ image }} wait=true region={{ region }} keypair={{ keypair }} vpc_subnet_id={{ subnet }} count={{ instance_count }}
    register: ec2

  - name: Add instance to local host group
    local_action: lineinfile dest=ansible_hosts regexp="{{ item.public_ip }}" insertafter="\[{{ application }}\]" line="{{ item.public_ip }} ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/ec2-keys/{{ keypair }}.pem" state=present
    with_items: ec2.instances
```

But, I have to agree that it's generally not something you want to do.  I found it to be quite a pain.  I've since switched to using add_host and life is much better.  BTW, application would be the value I used for the group name...

Answer (score 9):

I am doing the same, having written a play that creates servers from a dict (approximately 53 servers at a go, dynamically creating a full test environment).  To use a static hosts file, I add the following:

```
- name: Create in-memory inventory
  add_host:
    name: "{{ item.value.ServerName }}"
    groups: "{{ item.value.RoleTag }},tag_Environment_{{ env_name }}"
  when: item.value.template is defined 
  with_dict: server_details  

- name: create file
  become: yes
  template:
    src: ansible-hosts.j2
    dest: "{{ wm_inventory_file }}"
```

The ansible-hosts.j2 template is simply:

```
{% for item in groups %}

[{{item}}]
{%   for entry in groups[item] %}
{{ entry }}
{%   endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way for this playbook to retain the my_droplet.ip_address
>   variable and save the TBA in the hosts file instead of having to
>   manually copy-pasta it there?

You can retain the ip address of your new host by using the [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/add_host_module.html) module which allows you to dynamically change the in-memory inventory during an ansible-playbook run.  This is useful for when you want to provision a new host and then configure it in a single playbook.

For example

```
local_action: >
  add_host
    hostname={{ my_droplet.droplet.id }}
    groupname=launched
```

And then later in your playbook:

```
- name: Configure instance(s)
  hosts: launched
  tasks:
    ...
```

the second part of your questions:

> ... and save the TBA in the hosts file instead of having to
>    manually copy-pasta it there?

There is no built-in ansible way to write additions to the inventory file that is on disk. This is generally not something you want to do. In this case you would need to add it or use a [dynamic inventory script](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) to discover the host for future configuration runs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dynamic inventory script for this. Using `name` to distinguish instances, you can subsequently refer to your droplets.

Check https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/digital_ocean.py for an example script.